# finding the character at 'wildcard' position

Tags: json, powershell

I'm trying to parse a JSON string which has been flattened from a relational dataset from the looks of it... Into a CSV in order to import into an Oracle database. I have name/value pairs similar to this (simplified) example

```
Device.1.Service.1.Channel.1.someProperty : 1,
Device.1.Service.1.Channel.1.someOtherProperty : "billy",
Device.1.Service.1.Channel.2.someProperty : 8,
Device.1.Service.1.Channel.2.someOtherProperty : "frank",
Device.1.Service.1.Channel.3.someProperty : 12,
Device.1.Service.1.Channel.3.someOtherProperty : "sam",
Device.1.Service.2.Channel.1.someProperty : 3,
Device.1.Service.2.Channel.1.someOtherProperty : "john",
```

EDIT: A .json file with a similar structure is produced per day per device. So when consolidated `(Get-Content .\*.json -Raw`) I see the same property names occur many times in console.

As part of the conversion, I'd like parts of the property name to become fields in the database. This will enable us to visualise the data better using dynamic slider filters etc. later.

```
| Device | Service | Channel | someOtherProperty |    
|   1    |   1     |    1    |    billy          | 
|   1    |   1     |    2    |    frank          |
|   1    |   1     |    3    |    sam            |
```

Right now, I'm using the cmdlet `ConvertFrom-Json`. I'm then selecting the fields (out of nearly 2000 possible fields) using wildcards. The number of channels for example is dynamic.

```bsh
Get-Content .\*.json -Raw |  ConvertFrom-Json |      
    Select Device.1.Service.1.Channel.?.someOtherProperty
```

Which returns a `PSCustomObject`. I'd like to figure out the channel number and use that as a derived field. Pseudo example:

```bsh
Select @{n="Channel";e={$_.getCharAtWildcard()}},
       $_.theValueofTheCurrentObject()
```

If I pipe the data selected (using wildcard) to `Get-Member`, the `PSCostomObject` contains method names as well as my field names (but not the values).

I'm confused about how I access the field name (since 'Name' gives blank rows), then extract the channel number (the character at wildcard position), and then the value to structure my output correctly.

Any pointers? Googled and have a lynda.com sub, but can't seem to find a solution to this specific problem - probably because I'm not using the correct terms?

```bsh
##  ANSGAR's SOLUTION - WORKS FOR SINGLE FILE ##

$dataDir = "C:\ps_json2csv\dummydata"
CD $dataDir

$dict = Get-Content .\*.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json | Select -Expand data
$p  = 'DvbId'
$re = "frontend\.(\d+)\.logicalchannel\.(\d+)\.service\.(\d+)\..*?\.$p"

## modified regex to match my data, example string: FrontEnd.2.LogicalChannel.3.Service.1.stat.DvbId 

$fullset = $dict.PSObject.Properties | Where-Object {
    $_.Name -match $re
} | ForEach-Object {
    $prop = [ordered]@{
        FrontEnd       = $matches[1]
        LogicalChannel = $matches[2]
        Service        = $matches[3]
        $p             = $_.Value
    }
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $prop
}

## inspect $dict - its populated
## inspect $fullset  - its empty! :(
```

Data of which is 2 files contained in *C:\ps_json2csv\dummydata* :

File1.json

```
{
    "data": {
        "Device.1.Service.1.ChannelInfo.Channel.1.Stats.someProperty" : "1",
        "Device.1.Service.1.ChannelInfo.Channel.2.Stats.someProperty" : "8",
        "Device.1.Service.1.ChannelInfo.Channel.3.Stats.someProperty" : "12",
        "FrontEnd.2.LogicalChannel.3.Service.1.stat.DvbId" : "john",
        "FrontEnd.2.LogicalChannel.3.Service.2.stat.DvbId" : "billy",
        "FrontEnd.2.LogicalChannel.3.Service.3.stat.DvbId" : "frank",
        "FrontEnd.2.LogicalChannel.4.Service.1.stat.DvbId" : "sam",
        "Device.1.Service.2.ChannelInfo.Channel.1.Stats.someProperty" : "3",        
        "Some.value.im.not.intersted.in.just.yet": "Sat Jan 1 00:00:00 GMT 0001",
        "foo.bar" : "0",
        "random.stuff" : "hi there"
    }
}
```

File2.json

```
 {
    "data": {
        "Device.1.Service.1.ChannelInfo.Channel.1.Stats.someProperty" : "0",
        "Device.1.Service.1.ChannelInfo.Channel.2.Stats.someProperty" : "7",
        "Device.1.Service.1.ChannelInfo.Channel.3.Stats.someProperty" : "6",
        "FrontEnd.2.LogicalChannel.3.Service.1.stat.DvbId" : "john",
        "FrontEnd.2.LogicalChannel.3.Service.2.stat.DvbId" : "billy",
        "FrontEnd.2.LogicalChannel.3.Service.3.stat.DvbId" : "frank",
        "FrontEnd.2.LogicalChannel.4.Service.1.stat.DvbId" : "sam",
        "Device.1.Service.2.ChannelInfo.Channel.1.Stats.someProperty" : "4",        
        "Some.value.im.not.intersted.in.just.yet": "Sun Jan 2 00:00:00 GMT 0001",
        "foo.bar" : "0",
        "random.stuff" : "hi there"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably use a regular expression match to filter and extract your data:

```
$p  = 'someOtherProperty'
$re = "device\.(\d+)\.service\.(\d+)\..*?\.channel\.(\d+)\..*?\.$p"

$fullset = $dict.PSObject.Properties | Where-Object {
    $_.Name -match $re
} | ForEach-Object {
    $prop = [ordered]@{
        Device  = $matches[1]
        Service = $matches[2]
        Channel = $matches[3]
        $p      = $_.Value
    }
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $prop
}
```

Comment: This is good and very useful however, I've found that the if in the data files, the property name is the same, only the last appears in the output. To demonstrate. Use data such as the following... (where channel 1 is repeated, only one of them makes it to the output)

Comment: "Device.1.Service.1.ChannelInfo.Channel.1.Stats.someProperty" : "1",
        "Device.1.Service.1.ChannelInfo.Channel.1.Stats.someOtherProperty" : "billy",
        "Device.1.Service.1.ChannelInfo.Channel.2.Stats.someProperty" : "8",
        "Device.1.Service.1.ChannelInfo.Channel.2.Stats.someOtherProperty" : "frank",
        "Device.1.Service.1.ChannelInfo.Channel.3.Stats.someProperty" : 12,
        "Device.1.Service.1.ChannelInfo.Channel.1.Stats.someOtherProperty" : "sam"

Comment: @lee_dabiker That's how JSON works. JSON is a textual representation of object data. Objects can't have two properties with the same name.

Comment: The data is captured every day. A new file per day with all parameters repeated. One of the parameters in the file is a user ID and another a timestamp. after converting to JSON in Powershell, select-object (with a wildcard) still manages to maintain all repetitive properties for each day.

Comment: JSON and `ConvertFrom-Json` don't work that way. If your actual data looks like your sample data then you will get only the last value from duplicate properties. Otherwise please provide a sample that actually resembles your real data.

Comment: ok, I understand. I was playing around with how to represent the data so it would be easy for someone to copy and paste to play around with - but I can't replicate the behaviour in a single string. If you take the data contained within $content (as it exists inside the single quotes) and paste to a plain text file (.json file) and then do the same to a second file and perhaps just increment the timestamp by a day - Then I use: `Get-Content .\*.json -Raw |  ConvertFrom-Json | ` to pull all the JSON from files within the one directory. The repeated prop names persist, but the data is structured

Comment: Please avoid extended discussion in comments. If you need to provide additonal information: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43345140/edit) your question. Make code samles so that they allow us to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather convert a string of this syntax into a `PSObject` with the entire set of your properties. Like this:

```
$dict=Get-Content .\*.json -Raw |  ConvertFrom-Json
$fullset=$dict.psobject.properties | % {
    $parse=$_.name.split('.')
    $parse+=,$_.value # since JSON values might be non-plain, we need to add the value as single object
    $obj=new-object psobject
    for ($i=0;$i -lt $parse.length;$i+=2) { # name-value
        $v1=$parse[$i]
        $v2=$parse[1+$i]
        $obj | add-member -type noteproperty -name $v1 -value $v2
    }
    $obj
 }
```

Then you parse `$fullset` like you would with a normal list with `where {$_.device -eq '1' -and $_.someOtherProperty -ne $null}` etc.

Comment: I'd like to fully understand what the script block is doing before saying - I can't see how this will allow me to parse a dynamic number of Channels, Services or Devices. I want to make all the data available to analysts. it must be in DB for visualisation software to link to. Wouldn't I have to query e.g. where $_.Channel -eq 99 (if it exists ) and everything before that channel and use Select-object with a hardcode a label?

Comment: Im trying to learn powershell so will be missing some of the basic concepts. But the script throws an error because its trying to create a name which already exists. and the name it created (and is trying to overwrite) looks like an array/object... i.e add-member : Cannot add a member with the name "@{someName=someValue;  someOtherName=somOtherValue; somethingElse=aValue ..... etc] }"

Comment: Ah, got it. When the value in a JSON is an array/object (a nested object), the `$parse+=$_.value` flattens the array while I don't need it to do that. It should remain a single element. Will update tomorrow, as I don't have time right now.

Comment: Ok, your example works with a sample and simplified data set. I see $fullset is in table format in the console which I think will work for me - thanks very much for that. To integrate with my actual data - i need to understand the script.

Comment: 1. how does dict.psobject.properties work? when i peform get-member on the psobject, the name an values are contained in in a property named SyncRoot... 2. you are splitting the prop name string by '.' and putting into an array ($parse)? is this indivudual segments of the name? is the array length 7?  then pushing the prop value to the end of the array? how do i inspect $_.name and $_.value... and also $parse at this point... 3. create a new psobject  and iterate over the $parse array (why steps of 2?)

Comment: One potential important nugget is that prop name in the actual data set are more like this:  __Device.1.Service.1. _ChannelInfo_ .Channel.1. _Stats_ .someO‌​therProperty : "hi"__  So not always a name-value pair pattern - any hints greatly appreaciated

Comment: The add an array problem was solved simple as heck. Replace `$parse+=$_.value` with `$parse+=,$_.value` and note the comma. Powershell really likes expanding arrays everywhere possible, and this trick with comma is to prevent auto-expansion of an array while adding to another array.

Comment: With this "important nugget" of yours, the task isn't as easy as split by name-value. What is that `ChannelInfo` - a static classifier? If yes, you plain drop it from `$parse` so that the array remains a name-value.